# What happens if a proper design has been not followed for an enterprise application

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I’ve been outsourced  for an ASP.Net project of another organization to  build a large enterprise application. Currently almost 80% of the work has been completed. I found that the developers did not implemented any architecture in this application. All the work is done in the code behind file (*.aspx.cs). Even the database calls, sql scripts, etc.  are on the code behind file. The entire solution has only one project, which is a Website. All the coding, .aspx file etc. comes under it.
I know that the maintainability , catering to change requests, etc. of this project will be a nightmare.

But I would like know about the impact for the functionality of this project once the no of users increased from hundreds to thousands and more.

Will it be an issue, for not having a Data access layer and maintaining db connections in a once single place?

What will be the overall impact of the project from the functionality wise due to not implementing proper system architecture?

I need some hard point to convince them to go for a proper system architecture, which may be a whole system rewrite. So would be grateful if you are able to share your expertise of this matter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though, this is very broad question…

I think there are well known reason behind using a kind of an architecture to application developments.

Basically using architecture will reduce the complexity of an application. This can be done by using following best practices, design patterns and which brings us the flexibility and high usability.

Since you mention that code been done in code behind files we can guarantee that it’s violating one of the key design principles like ***Separation of concerns*** and ***DRY*** (Don’t repeat yourself). That is only a single factor. There can be many.

I think you might gain a good idea if you could read this article about [Software Architecture and Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658093)
Also another good one about [Motivating Software Architecture](http://www.bredemeyer.com/why.htm)

Answer (score 2):

There is only two kinds of software, software that works and software that does not.  The customers/users do not care what goes on behind the scenes.

Maintaining software is a real reason for concern, however you can have maintainable spaghetti code, but it's highly un-likely in the enterprise.

Proper architecture is specific to your software solution regarding goals for maintainability, scalibity and extensibility.  There are trad-offs in architectural goals that often conflict.

There's no single answer, just patterns that solve common problems.

[Microsoft Application Architecture Guide, 2nd Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx)